# Why icon of an MFC ribbon gallery button does not change?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, ribbon-control

I am trying to create an MFC ribbon gallery button (similar to mspaint brushes button) using Visual Studio 2010 ribbon wizard.

step1  I created a gallery button, changed button mode to true, set columns to 4, icon width to 32,  set a large icon to it.

step2  I added icons to gallery button.

everything looks fine except that when I select an icon from drop down menu of the gallery button,
the main icon of the gallery button stays the same.

How can I change the gallery button icon to the selected icon?

Comment: Welcome. May you post your code?